# Where does CultureInfo data come from?

Tags: c#, .net

When I create a culture info object for *en-CA* (
    `new CultureInfo("en-CA")`) I'm getting a different `ShortDatePattern` in my production environment than in my development environment.

I don't have access to the production server then I'm just assuming that the information that fills the object comes from regional settings.

I tried to change my development regional settings to have a different `ShortDatePattern` for *en-CA* but I'm still getting `"MM/dd/yyyy"` instead of `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

Where does this configuration come from and what could be the difference between my local environment and the production environment that is returning a different `ShortDatePattern` for the same CultureInfo?

**Code:**

```
var someDate = DateTime.now;
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
var formatedDate = someDate.ToString(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a reference from MSDN, check it

Comment: Could you include the code you are using? In particular what you are doing to change the short date pattern for the culture?

Comment: the culture information comes from the machine the application is running on. So if youre in the US, your culter info would be US formats, and if youre running the same app in the UK it would be UK formats.

Comment: @SimonPrice: that is true for the default culture but the en-CA culture is the canadian english culture and really shouldn't vary based on the machine. I suspect chances are that the OP is accidentally using the default culture instead of the canadian one which is why I asked for code...

Comment: You can override date/time/numeric formats for a culture in Windows control panel. Whatever overrides you do there will be used by .net for the same culture as the user's culture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `CultureInfo` constructor uses the customised user configuration by default. Use the constructor that takes an extra `bool` parameter `useUserOverride` and pass `false`.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h898a16(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **useUserOverride**
>
> A Boolean that denotes whether to use the user-selected culture settings (true) or the default culture settings (false).

Answer (score 0):

It's the machine culture, in order to force a culture on your app you have to add it in the web config or the app config

> To set the UI culture and culture for all pages, add a globalization section to the Web.config file, and then set the uiculture and culture attributes, as shown in the following example:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-CA" culture="en-CA" />
```

here is the [MSDN Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to set a global culture or something like that, I'm using CultureInfo to  format some DateTime fields with ShortDatePattern now my problem is that ShortDatePattern in dev env is giving me "dd/MM/yyyy" but the same ShortDatePattern of the same CultureInfo is giving me "yyyy-MM-dd" in production

Comment: Could you please post your code and is it a windows app or a web app